# Use $slice only in Aggregation in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have Database Employee Model like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("svdfvdfvfvdf dfv "),
    "name" : "XXXXXX",
    "code" : "XXXXX",
    "phone" : "XXXXXXX",
    "email" : "XXXXXXX",
    "EmpDb_Emp_id" : 7,
    "organization" : ObjectId("wwwwwwwww444cdc"),
    "shiftType" : ObjectId("2323232323232")
}
```

the data which i receive in aggregate is also an array So want TO retrive data from that .

I want to use $slice only in aggregate. So, that I want to implement Pagination in it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: $slice only works on array, and your document doesn't contain any... Please add the expected results, it's not very clear

Comment: the data which i receive in aggregate is also an array So Can I retrive data from that  ???

Comment: which date ? What's your aggregagtion query ?

Comment: 100 says the "array" is actually the full output of the aggregation. That's the default for the node driver as is mongoose. Therefore you use [`$skip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/) and [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/). No arrays here.